# FieldError: Unsupported lookup for CharField or join on the field not permitted on Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, search

Why do I get this error: `FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'unaccent' for CharField or join on the field not permitted`?

## Info

Language: Python
Platform: Django
Database: PostgreSQL

## Code

View:

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get("query")
    searched = Book.objects.filter(title__unaccent__icontains=query) # Error here
    return render(request, "main/search.html", {
        "query": query,
        "searched": searched,
    })
```

## Expected output

Unaccent the query and search for the unaccented version in the database.

## Description

I get the error `FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'unaccent' for CharField or join on the field not permitted` when I try to query the database using `__unaccent` while using the advanced search features mentioned in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/search/#a-database-s-more-advanced-comparison-functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `unaccent` or any other PostgreSQL specific lookup, first

1. Add `django.contrib.postgres` to your `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS`.
2. Activate the lookup's extension on PostgreSQL. [For `unaccent`, click here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) (under "Usage"), or you could
3. Perform the extension's migration operation. For `unaccent`, the extension is called `UnaccentExtension`. You can do this migration operation by

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations --empty your_app_name
```

Then head over to the migration file created in the `migrations` folder of your app. If you're not sure which one is the file that was just created, the newest file is usually the one you created. To be extra careful, look into the terminal output that was displayed after you ran the above command. It is going to include the name of the file under the heading `Migrations for your_app_name`.

Then, in that file, delete the content and paste this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import UnaccentExtension
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('<your_app_name>', '<previous_migration_file>'),
    ]

    operations = [
        UnaccentExtension()
    ]
```

In the above code, replace `<your_app_name>` with the name of your app, and `previous_migration_file` with the name of the migration file before this one, **not including the `.py` file extension**. To find the previous migration file, look at the number of the migration file you're in (for example, in `0008_auto_20220104_1352`, `0008` is the number of the file) and subtract 1 (for example, the previous file of `0008_auto_20220104_1352` is going to start with `0007`).

After making the changes, `python3 manage.py migrate` to migrate your changes. You can now access the `unaccent` extension.